# Binding HTML template to data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-compile, angularjs-templates

I have a simple HTML template like following

```
<p>{{data.id}}</p>
```

And can I just compile it with a data object to a string, I do not want to bind it with any scope.

Like

```
var data = {id:123}; 
var result = $compile(html)(data);
```

Thanks!

Added [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hyhkLWhboIYqSIcUkHvI?p=preview).

Comment: Your plunkr code doesn't match your question. What are you trying to do? Bind properties without a scope? Angular won't do that.
Are you trying to learn how to $compile some html and add it to your page? If so, please update your question.

Comment: It seems AngularJS does not support it.. I do not want scope

Comment: If you want to bind to a property, it must be on a scope. What's the problem with that?

Comment: never mind. I just tried to use angular as a template generator